# ViewPagerIndicator dots not showing on top ?its showing below the view .how to fix

Tags: xamarin.android

[image: Link of the Code that i have implemented]

Here is the link to detail code 
[Link of the Code that i have implemented](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/182975/viewpage-indicator-dots-appearing-under-the-blow-of-view-how-to-show-dots-on-hover-or-top-the-view#latest)

Answer (score 0):

I use your code and added some `TextInputLayouts` there, the Indicator dots do show on top.

I think you should check the `TextInputLayouts` layout in layout1, layout2, layout3, layout4.

Here is the result:

[image: gif]

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Android-CarouselView) and you can check.

Feel free to ask me any question.